# What happened to evince.desktop?

Tags: debian, evince

I just noticed that I couldn't find the `.desktop` file for `evince`. It looks like it got removed from a recent update.

I am on debian testing.

Anyone know how to restore it or where to report this?

Comment: What is the output of `xdg-mime query default application/pdf` ?

Comment: Anyway this file is still found in debian's search engine: https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=buster&arch=any&mode=path&searchon=contents&keywords=evince.desktop

Comment: @GAD3R: `org.gnome.Evince.desktop`

Comment: Reportbug : https://wiki.debian.org/reportbug